# Chemical equilibrium and free energy

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a major confusion over the relationship between free energy change and the equilibrium constant.
I have read that $\Delta G_0= -RT\ln K$.

My first doubt is, does $\Delta G_0$ refer to free energy change ONLY at 25C?
Does $\Delta G_0$ make sense for any other temperature?

Secondly, the "T" in the equation
Does it also have to be the same temperature as the temperature for which we write $\Delta G_0$? (ie,25C)
If not so, can we write any temperature and obtain the corresponding K value?

Please explain.

If G0 can be defined for other temperatures, does that mean that S0 and H0 can also be defined for other temperatures?

Comment: It can be defined for any temperature. Second part - yes, you write the temperature for which you calculated ΔG at. I'm 99% sure this is a duplicate of something, although I will admit that the exact duplicate is not easy to find, not least because there are like 50 questions on this site with poor unspecific titles like "Gibbs free energy confusion".

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: It's ok. That's why I chose to give you a brief answer as well. Also yes, standard entropy and enthalpy changes can also be defined for other temperatures. The thermodynamic standard state only stipulates unit activity (which can be approximated by unit concentration) and not a temperature.

Comment: But I am assuming that pressure should be 1atmosphere?

Comment: I have never come across a single book that explains all these small details of thermodynamics

Comment: Yes, its shocking.  $\Delta G^0$ refers to the change in free energy between the following two thermodynamic equilibrium states:  State 1:  Pure reactants in separate containers, each at temperature T and 1 atm. pressure.  State 2:  Pure products in separate containers each at temperature T and 1 atm pressure.

Comment: I believe the new standard is 1 bar. But yeah.